# Creating skills through REST API returning Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to create Skills through the REST API (in an apex class) and I am getting a 401 back from salesforce.

Note - Skills are new and cannot be inserted through normal DML operations, hence the need for REST.

Here is the code:

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    if(LiveAgentPreChat__c.getInstance('LiveAgentPreChatConfig')!=null) {
        req.setEndpoint(LiveAgentPreChat__c.getInstance('LiveAgentPreChatConfig').WebserviceEndPoint__c +'/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/Skill/');
    }
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req.setBody('{"DeveloperName": "' + DevName + '","MasterLabel": "' + SklLabel + '"}');
    Http http = new Http();
    return req;
```

**EDIT** - I have found a solution. Since I am using the session Id I do need to use Bearer instead of OAuth. Also, this method is getting called in a batch class, so UserInfo.getSessionId() returns null in a batch. Just grabbed the session Id from a different spot and passed it to the method and it worked.

Comment: Shouldn't the authorization be Bearer rather than OAuth?

Comment: @DougB Actually that line should be commented out. Technically I already have a session Id since this this is all within the same salesforce instance.

Comment: Does that apply when you are making a callout? Can you try it with the "Authorization" "Bearer <SessionID>" ?

Comment: I figured out a solution @DougB - I posted an edit in my question. Your suggestion was part of it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped some :)

Comment: I am also in a similar situation. What is your workaround for grabbing the session Id when calling the method from a batch class?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "Just grabbed the session Id from a different spot" Which different spot would that be?

Comment: Even in the top most caller, the Scheduler class, the session id is null :-(